# Integer Underflow when initializing for loop variable with size_t

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, unsigned, size-t

I was running the code example below, initially trying to print a character array backwards where `count` represented the number of characters in the array. Everytime I ran the for loop, `i` was not initalized to `count - 1` instead it was initialized to some very large number. But outside the loop, i is properly initalized to 4. I can't explain why this is happening.

```
size_t count {5};
size_t i {count - 1UL}; // i is initalized to 4

for(size_t i {count - 1}; i >= 0UL; --i) {
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
} // infinite loop, i is initalized to 18446744073709141874
```

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned, so it is always `>= 0`.

Comment: So I should only ever use loop counters with integers when iterating backwards?

Comment: Terminology update, [there is no such thing as "integer underflow"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An "unsigned" integer does not have a sign and is always nonnegative.  If you do `--i` on `i = 0` then you will get the maximum value of `std::size_t`.

Do this instead:

```
// iterates from (count - 1) to 0
for (std::size_t i = count; i--;)
```

So how does this work?  `i--` is the postfix decrement operator, which returns the prior value of `i`.  This way, the loop condition is actually comparing `count, ..., 1` to zero, while in the loop we get `count - 1, ..., 0`.

A more generalized version of this idiom is sometimes called the [`-->` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1642028):

```
// iterates from (high - 1) to low
for (std::size_t i = high; i-- > low;)
```

Comment: Reads perfect now :-)

Answer (score 1):

`std::size_t` is unsigned integer type. So values of the type never can be negative.

Rewrite the loop like

```
std::size_t i {count - 1};

do
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
} while ( i-- );
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `i` in the outer scope is unused and shaded, secondly an unsigned integer is always greater than or equal to `0`. You could have your compiler detect these if only you turned on your [compiler warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/QN4cMz):

```
<source>:7:38: error: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Werror=type-limits]

    7 |     for(std::size_t i {count - 1}; i >= 0UL; --i) {

      |                                    ~~^~~~~~

<source>:5:17: error: unused variable 'i' [-Werror=unused-variable]

    5 |     std::size_t i {count - 1UL}; // i is initalized to 4

      |
```

Solution:

```
for (unsigned long long i = 4ull; i != -1ull; --i) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```